# How can a Stored Procedure's Group By clause have Different Numbers Of Columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_timeline`
(
    IN  in_unit VARCHAR(255)
)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE in_unit
            WHEN 'MICROSECOND' THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, CONCAT("%Y-%m-%d %H:",LPAD(SECOND(`ts`) DIV 6,2,0),":%s"))
            WHEN 'SECOND'      THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, CONCAT("%Y-%m-%d %H:",LPAD(SECOND(`ts`) DIV 6,2,0),":%s"))
            WHEN 'MINUTE'      THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, CONCAT("%Y-%m-%d %H:",LPAD(SECOND(`ts`) DIV 6,2,0),":%s"))
            WHEN 'HOUR'        THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, CONCAT("%Y-%m-%d %H:",LPAD(SECOND(`ts`) DIV 6,2,0),":%s"))
            WHEN 'DAY'         THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, CONCAT("%Y-%m-%d %H:",LPAD(SECOND(`ts`) DIV 6,2,0),":%s"))
            WHEN 'WEEK'        THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, CONCAT("%Y-%m-%d %H:",LPAD(MINUTE(`ts`) DIV 6,2,0),":00"))
            WHEN 'MONTH'       THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, CONCAT("%Y-%m-%d ",LPAD(HOUR(`ts`) DIV 6,2,0),":00:00"))
            WHEN 'YEAR'        THEN DATE_FORMAT(`ts`, "%Y-%m-%d %0:00:00")
        END                 AS `time`,
        COUNT(*)            AS `count`
    FROM
        `session`
    GROUP BY
        CASE in_unit
            WHEN
                'MICROSECOND'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`),
                DAY(`ts`),
                HOUR(`ts`),
                MINUTE(`ts`),
                SECOND(`ts`),
                MICROSECOND(`ts`) DIV 100
            )
            WHEN
                'SECOND'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`),
                DAY(`ts`),
                HOUR(`ts`),
                MINUTE(`ts`),
                SECOND(`ts`),
                MICROSECOND(`ts`) DIV 100
            )
            WHEN
                'MINUTE'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`),
                DAY(`ts`),
                HOUR(`ts`),
                MINUTE(`ts`),
                SECOND(`ts`),
                MICROSECOND(`ts`) DIV 100
            )
            WHEN
                'HOUR'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`),
                DAY(`ts`),
                HOUR(`ts`),
                MINUTE(`ts`),
                SECOND(`ts`) DIV 6
            )
            WHEN
                'DAY'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`),
                DAY(`ts`),
                HOUR(`ts`),
                MINUTE(`ts`) DIV 6
            )
            WHEN
                'WEEK'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`),
                DAY(`ts`),
                HOUR(`ts`)
            )
            WHEN
                'MONTH'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`),
                DAY(`ts`)
            )
            WHEN
                'YEAR'
            THEN
            (
                YEAR(`ts`),
                MONTH(`ts`),
                WEEK(`ts`)
            )
        END
;
END
//
```

I am attempting to use a case statement in the group by clause to group by 8,7,6,5,4, or 3 columns depending on the unit that was passed into the stored procedure, but am receiving an "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)". What can I do to achieve this result without having to utilize a prepared query through concatenation? (I am using MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(ts),
         (case when in_unit in ('Month', . . .) then MONTH(`ts`) end),
         (case when in_unit in ('Week', . . .) then WEEK(`ts`) end),
         . . .
```

The relationship between the names of the units and the choice of `group by` variables is fully clear to me.  But basically, you just need to add a condition to each possible variable.